# drupal 7 disable the sidebar from japanese homepage

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-views

I've a website which is using 2 languages (ENG, JP). I created a block which is displaying every page except homepage, only. I place "home and ja" at "All pages except those listed". But at eng homepage, the block is not displaying. but at ja homepage, the block is displaying.

How can I do?

Comment: Would you please give the links to check it live?

Comment: http://dev.myanmarbravo.com/ja

Comment: but the url is http://dev.myanmarbravo.com/ja/home. it is ok. How should I do?

Comment: I am seeing that theres no difference between the pages.

Comment: Pls look at again. I'm working on it.

Comment: What did you placed at the text box? Please write the exact value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just enter "`<front>`" as the value. Remove "home and ja". This should work great.